# iwlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, qt

This is the first time for me to use Linux and its development tools. When I was trying to build the project I have to read, I had an error:

```
/home/charlie/AODV/llf.c:36: error: iwlib.h: No such file or directory
```

I was building the project with Qt. Beforehand, I installed libnl by make and make install, but the problem was not resolved. I am wondering if I did not install libel correctly or there are something more I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Linux development.

You need to install `libiw` and it's development header(s).

How to do this is distribution dependant. On my Debian (should be more or less the same on any Debian based distro like Ubuntu):

```
jbm@sumo:~$ apt-cache search libiw
libiw-dev - Wireless tools - development files
libiw30 - Wireless tools - library
```

`libiw30` is the binary lib, and the `*-dev` package is for it's header file(s), plus sometimes some docs (man pages etc). So:

```
jbm@sumo:~$ sudo apt-get install libiw-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
[...]
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libiw30
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libiw-dev libiw30
```

Note how installing the header(s) for a lib rightfully install the library as well.

After install:

```
jbm@sumo:~$ find /usr/include/ -name iwlib.h
/usr/include/iwlib.h

jbm@sumo:~$ find /usr/lib -name "libiw*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiw.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiw.a
```

Note that:

- `/usr/include` is part of the standard search path for headers of your
  gcc toolchain, so you don't need to add a peculiar `-I` (for "include")
  option.
- `/usr/lib` is the same for lib binaries, so no need any `-l` or
  `-L` (for "link") option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say to the compiler where to look for the header file. Use the -Idir option with dir the directory where the header file is.